# Kivy: refresh RecycleView data

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-recycleview

I saw different posts talking about that: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63007345/refresh-recycle-view-on-data-changes-in-kivy) and [THERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714587/how-to-refresh-kivy-recycleview-every-time-data-changes).

But they are complex solutions when I just want to understand what is the exact line that make the changement. I have the access to the `RecycleView`

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory as F
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

KV = '''
<Item>:
RecycleView:
    data: app.data
    viewclass: 'Row'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        id: recycle_view
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        default_size: 0, dp(40)
'''


def _on_text(instance, value):
    recycle_view = instance.app.screen.ids["recycle_view"]
    print(recycle_view,"value that I want to update in the recycle_view:",value)
    #recycle_view.data ? I don't know how to access the data and change it !


class Row(F.TextInput):

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        super().on_kv_post(base_widget)
        self.app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        self.bind(text=_on_text)

class Application(MDApp):
    data = ListProperty()

    def build(self):
        self.data = [
            {'index': i, 'text': 'hello {}'.format(i)}
            for i in range(40)
        ]
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.screen


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I find out that I missed the fact that I was playing with `RecycleBoxlaout` and not `RecycleView`.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory as F
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

KV = '''
<Item>:
RecycleView:
    data: app.data
    viewclass: 'Row'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        id: recycle_boxlayout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        default_size: 0, dp(40)
'''


def _on_text(instance, value):
    instance.app.screen.data[instance.index]["text"] = value


class Row(F.TextInput):

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        super().on_kv_post(base_widget)
        self.app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        self.counter = -1
        self.bind(text=_on_text)

class Application(MDApp):
    data = ListProperty()

    def build(self):
        self.data = [
            {'index': i, 'text': 'hello {}'.format(i)}
            for i in range(40)
        ]
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.screen


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```